# Magento jQuery Image Scaling issue, image not resizing

Tags: magento-1.9, conflict, image-resizing, external-images

We have just moved to a new server & we have around 800+ cms pages with images. Some of the pages have images where we have used tag to specify the width & height, but the issue is the images are coming across with original size. While testing we could presume that the images are not scaling because of jquery, though we have used noConflict() but of no use. We are using Jquery-2.1.1.

Please advise me on how can we resolve the issue & make the image load in required size. As editing each page will be a tiring job to do.

Thanks

Comment: Any advise on this issue.

Comment: Please tell me how can i remove jquery from a specific CMS page.